# why is my variable always decremented to zero?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I am writing a bowling script for fun. I did a homework assignment a few months ago and got it working in C++ but now I want to do it in bash because I like it better.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((teamPlayer = 1 ; teamPlayer <= 5; teamPlayer++ )); do

        for ((bowlingGame = 1; bowlingGame <=3; bowlingGame++)); do

            read -p "Please enter the bowling score for Player number $teamPlayer in game number $bowlingGame: "

                    while [[ -z $REPLY  ]] || (( $REPLY > 300 ||  $REPLY < 1 )) || [[ ! $REPLY =~ [[:digit:]] ]]; do

                        if ((teamPlayer >=1 )); then 
                            (( bowlingScores +- REPLY ))
                            ((teamPlayer-1))
                            ((bowlingGame-1)) 
                        fi

                        echo -e "\nError Try Again!"

                        read -p "Please enter the bowling score for Player number $teamPlayer in game number $bowlingGame: "
                    done

            (( bowlingScores += REPLY ))

    done

    (( bowlingScores += average ))

    echo "The average for player number $teamPlayer is $((average/3))" 

    (( average--))

done

echo "The average score for the team is $((bowlingScores/15))"
```

The problem is when I try to get the average for each player, the average is always zero. I want to decrement the average VALUE only when the average is displayed. And the other problem is if I don't decrement the value, each player after player 1 gets a wrong average.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Got it to work. Here is the new code.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((teamPlayer = 1 ; teamPlayer <= 5; teamPlayer++ )); do

        for ((bowlingGame = 1; bowlingGame <=3; bowlingGame++)); do

            read -p "Please enter the bowling score for Player number $teamPlayer in game number $bowlingGame: "


                    while [[ -z $REPLY  ]] || (( $REPLY > 300 ||  $REPLY < 1 )) || [[ ! $REPLY =~ [[:digit:]] ]]; do

                        if ((teamPlayer >=1 || bowlingGame >=1 )); then 
                            (( bowlingScores +- REPLY ))
                            ((teamPlayer >=1)) && ((teamPlayer-1))
                            ((bowlingGame-1)) && ((teamPlayer-1))
                        fi

                        echo -e "\nError Try Again!"

                        read -p "Please enter the bowling score for Player number $teamPlayer in game number $bowlingGame: "
                    done

            (( bowlingScores += REPLY ))


            (( average += REPLY ))

    done



    echo "The average for player number $teamPlayer is $((average/3))" 

    average=0

done

echo "The average score for the team is $((bowlingScores/15))"

echo $bowlingScores
```

Comment: You don't have to duplicate the tags in the question title, the tags themselves are enough.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
(( bowlingScores +- REPLY ))
((teamPlayer-1))
((bowlingGame-1))
```

Should be:

```
(( bowlingScores += REPLY ))
((teamPlayer-=1))
((bowlingGame-=1))
```

Check:http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html

Comment: This answer contents are true. Also note that bash can only perform integer arithmetic. If you (OP) are expecting floating point numbers as answer, you won;t get it via simple division.

Comment: Thanks klashxx. I had fixed that first part  just before coming back to the site. I'll definitely check out the link.

Comment: However, I don't think the variables teamPlayer and bowlingGame should become -=1. I only want to decrement them if they equal 1. I will post my new code.